# Import error when using skvideo.io

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to import skvideo.io in python 3.6.3 but getting an import error. I installed skvideo through pip and it was installed successfully.

The is the error I am getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import skvideo.io   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skvideo__init__.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from .utils import check_output, where   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skvideo\utils__init__.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       from .edge import canny   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skvideo\utils\edge.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       import scipy.ndimage   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage__init__.py",
>   line 161, in 
>       from .filters import *   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py",
>   line 37, in 
>       from scipy.misc import doccer   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc__init__.py",
>   line 67, in 
>       from scipy.interpolate._pade import pade as _pade   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate__init__.py",
>   line 175, in 
>       from .interpolate import *   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       import scipy.linalg   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg__init__.py",
>   line 186, in 
>       from .misc import *   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       from .blas import get_blas_funcs   File "C:\Users\Hasan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py",
>   line 196, in 
>       from scipy.linalg import _fblas ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Can someone help me out

Comment: Your scipy (or numpy) install is broken. But it's impossible for us to debug this.

Comment: I used the unofficial windows libraries. might this be the problem ?

Comment: There are more than one inofficial windows binaries, sure it's a possible source. I always always recommend using anaconda!

Comment: ok I will uninstall scipy and numpy using pip and try using anaconda